# problem with setting the class path in manifest.mf within jar file

Tags: java

I have created the jar file,and I run it using command:-

> > java -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments...

then I got this error----
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer
    at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)

## ... 1 more

I removed this error by mentioning the full class path name,
Class-Path=/Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar  in MANIFEST.MF.
And now when I run it by using command:-

> > java -cp /Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments...
> >
> > ## its working properly.

But I want to mention only jar file name "hector-0.6.0-17.jar" in Class-Path in MANIFEST.MF.If I give full class path,then it will not work on others machine.And 
I have to run this jar on others machine.
And when I mention only jar file name "hector-0.6.0-17.jar",and I run it using command:-

> > java -cp /Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments...
> >     it is showing me same error message:-

--Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer
    at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)

## ... 1 more

I dont want to mention full class path name in MANIFEST.MF,so please tell me solution for this, or how to set only jar file name "hector-0.6.0-17.jar" to
Class-Path in MANIFEST.MF in the jar.

Comment: it seems you need to include dendency in your jar only and then give relative path in MENIFEST

Answer (score 2):

You have to write the relative class path in your manifest file. For example if your application has lib directory where all third party jars are held just add the following line to your manifest file:

`Class-Path: lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar`

now this `java -jar bin/niidle.jar arguments...` should work if your are running it from `/usr/local/`

I'd recommend you to put all your jar files in one directory, e.g. lib. It is easier to maintain. Bin directory should contain scripts.

Comment: Thank you AlexR,I did as you told,I typed command:>> java -jar bin/niidle.jar arguments...and excuted from /usr/local/ but then also same error getting:--

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer
 at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.....Please tell me solution