# problem with MANIFEST.MF in jar

Tags: java

I have created my jar file in the following folder:

> ```
> /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar
> ```

And I have one jarfile which is in the following folder

> ```
> /Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar
> ```

And this file 'hector-0.6.0-17.jar' I have to include in MANIFEST.MF in jar.

And when I mention class path in MANIFEST.MF as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager
Class-Path: /Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar
```

When I run this using command:

```
java -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar
```

It works properly..

But I dont want to give full Class-Path name, I have to give Class-Path as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager
Class-Path: lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar
```

And when I run this using command:

```
java -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar
```

It is showing error message:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer
>     at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:21)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer
>    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
>    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
>    ... 1 more
> ```

Please tell me solution for that...

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem with setting the class path in manifest.mf within jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667281/problem-with-setting-the-class-path-in-manifest-mf-within-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two solutions:

1. store hector-0.6.0-17.jar inside niidle.jar and use a relative path in Class-Path. E.g. `Class-Path: lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar`   (for niidle.jar/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar)
2. `java -cp /Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `lib` folder *in the folder where you are running the command*, put `hector-0.6.0-17.jar` in it and try running the command again.