# Why is my jar producing a NoClassDefFoundError when the class is listed in MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: java, manifest.mf

I have created jar in the following folder `usr/local/bin/niidle.jar` and my `MANIFEST.MF` file is as follows:

```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Main-Class: com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager
  Class-Path: hector-0.6.0-17.jar
```

I verified that the file `hector-0.6.0-17.jar` is also present in the folder:

> > /Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar

I don't want to give full class-path name in `MANIFEST.MF` file, because I have to run this jar on another machine. So I gave only jar file name `Class-Path=hector-0.6.0-17.jar` in MANIFEST.MF file.

In spite of mentioning the Class-Path in MANIFEST.MF file, when I run this using command:

> > java -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments...

It is showing the error message:

```
--Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer
     at
 com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:21)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
 me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer
     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
     ... 1 more
```

Please give me a solution for this error message.

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem with MANIFEST.MF in jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677342/problem-with-manifest-mf-in-jar)

Answer (score 2):

Class-Path is relative or absolute to the directory where your jar file is located.
so for your case you have to hector-0.6.0-17.jar to /usr/local/bin

Comment: hi,Reza,Thank you,......But I have niidle.jar file,and already there is one 'lib'folder,and in that folder there is 'hector-0.6.0-17.jar' file. So when I type command:>> java -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments..it is showing above error message:-Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:21) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)--any solution for this.

Comment: what happens if you move hector-o.6.-0-17.jar to /usr/local/bin?