# problem related to MANIFEST.MF in jar

Tags: java

I have created jar in folder /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar.

### And I have cerated MANIFEST.MF in jar as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager
Class-Path: hector-0.6.0-17.jar
```

---

And my 'hector-0.6.0-17.jar' file is present in following folder:

```
/Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar
```

---

And I have added this 'hector-0.6.0-17.jar' in niidle.jar folder as follows:

```
niidle.jar/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar
```

---

And when I run this using command:

```
java -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments....
```

---

then I am getting error message as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer
    at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 1 more
```

---

And When I run again using different command as follows:

```
java -cp /Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments.....
```

---------------Then also I am getting the same error message:--

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/prettyprint/hector/api/Serializer
    at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.prettyprint.hector.api.Serializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
    ... 1 more-------------
```

---

so tell me what is solution for that.or any modification in MANIFEST.MF in jar

Comment: possible duplicate of [problem with setting the class path in manifest.mf within jar file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667281/problem-with-setting-the-class-path-in-manifest-mf-within-jar-file)

Comment: So, Atul, are you having problems with the manifest in your jar?

Answer (score 2):

> java -cp /Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar arguments.....

You can't use the `-cp` switch together with the `-jar` switch.

From http://mindprod.com/jgloss/classpath.html:

> If you use the -jar option, java.exe **ignores the classpath**. It will only look in that jar!! Try using the manifest Class-Path instead to get Java to look in auxiliary jars

---

> And I have added this 'hector-0.6.0-17.jar' in niidle.jar folder as follows:

To my knowledge, you can't nest `.jar` files this way.

Since you have `Class-Path: hector-0.6.0-17.jar` you need to have the `needle.jar` and the `hector-0.6.0-17.jar` **side by side** and run `niidle.jar` from their common directory (using the `-jar` switch if you like).

Answer (score 0):

Line niidle.jar/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar is confusing. Is niidle.jar directory or file?
I'd suggest you to post your full manifest, directory structure, command line you are using and current working directory.

But generally you should write in your manifest:
Class-Path: hector-0.6.0-17.jar

then put all jars in one directory. Let's call it `foo`.
Now open command prompt, go to foo and run

java -jar niidle.jar args...

And I believe that everything will work. Then if you wish play with location of your jars.

Answer (score 0):

For setting up "jars within jars" take a look at this question:

[Classpath including JAR within a JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183292/classpath-including-jar-within-a-jar)