# some problem in jar file in java

Tags: java

I have created jar file for my project.
It is running successfully.
There is one 'lib' folder.
I have other jar files in this folder.
I added all these jar files in MANIFEST.MF in the jar as follows:

```
>>Class-Path:jar file names .... ...  ....
```

I run jar file as follows:

```
>>java -jar jarfile.jar arguments...
```

but problem is that I need to put this jar file where the 'lib' folder is located,
and if i want to run this jar on others machine,then i need to give this jar folder along with 'lib' folder.

but I dont want to give this jar along with 'lib' folder.

And when I try to put this jar outside the 'lib' folder,it is not working.

I have to give this only jar folder to other machine.so I can run my jar file on others machine.

Comment: so when you had decided not to share your jar,did u give your complete path to the other machine..like \\machinename\sharedfolder\jarname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you, but unless you implement your own custom class loader, you can not nest jar-files like that in Java. See for instance [this discussion](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t143595-jars-containing-jars.html).

You could however *merge* your jar files using tools such as [One-Jar](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-onejar/).

[Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4678524/problem-related-to-manifest-mf-in-jar/4678582#4678582).

(*woho, this was my 1000th answer* :)

Comment: I also think One-Jar is what is needed here. If this is a maven project, then the maven-assembly-plugin can do a similar job.